# I can't get values from some column of datagridview in this case

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

I created Datatable and DataAdapter via "Data Source Configuration Wizard" in visual Studio.

Each column of datagridiview was bound with DataPropertiesName.
So if I need to display some value, I will input a name to column of datagridview.

(By right Click on datagridview>click "Edit columns" and input the a column's name which it have in Data source Configuration Wizard.)

For example , 
I have two table in "Data Source Configuration Wizard"
[image]

Both datatable have a relationship with "UNIT_CODE" and "STOCK_UNIT" field

UNIT_CODE is primary key
and STOCK_UNIT is foreign key.

My Datagridview is bound with PACKAGES table.
Datagridview will display PKG_CODE,PKG_DESCR and **UNIT_DESCR** column.
which UNIT_DESCR is in UNIT table(Out of PACKAGE table).
So I must input "UNI_DESCR" plain text to DataPropertiesName of datagrid's column.

[image]

and using dataAdpater for fill data to gridview by these vb code.

```
      taUNITSTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatasourceName.UNITS)
      taPACKAGESTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatasourceName.PACKAGES)
```

Now UNIT_DESCR will display on datagridview.

Although UNIT_DESCR will shown values on datagridview 
but when I use below vb code for getting value from this column.

It will return **Nothing**.

```
     Datagridview1.Item(dgvUNIT_DESCR.Index,rows.Index).value
```

What should I do?

Edit for added some information. Below vb code is getting a value from datagridview.

```
     For Each row As DataGridViewRow In CtrlDataGridView1.Rows
          Dim str as String = String.Empty
          str = Datagridview1.Item(dgvUNIT_DESCR.Index,rows.Index).value
          MessegeBox.show(str.ToString)    
     Next
```

Comment: Where does the rows variable comes from ? Are u sure this has correct value ? I am not familiar with VB.net, what does dgvUNIT_DESCR.index means ?

Comment: dgvUNIT_DESCR.Index  refer to index of column on datagridview.

Comment: And where does the rows comes from ? Are u sure this has the correct value ?

Comment: Sure, Have you ever used "Data Source Configuration Wizard"?
If you have two table which it has a relation with a key. You can refer to all field of both tables by input  a column's name to DataPropertiesName properties.  if don't use design, you can use this code yourDatagridviewColumnName.DataPropertiesName  = "UNIT_DESCR"

Comment: I was just asking because from the code you posted it was not clear where the variable "rows" came from and how it was filled.  It is a long time ago that I used that wizard, most companies I work for it is forbidden to use it.

Comment: It is still not clear to me where "rows" came from, how is this filled, are u sure this has correct value.

Comment: I edited for adding some code. And if you don't understand about dgvUNIT_DESCR. Please to looking for second image.

Comment: I have no problem with dgvUNIT_DESCR, it is not what i am asking after. I asked where does the variable "rows" comes from and how is it filed. Please forget about dgvUNIT_DESCR because I am not asking for that and please focus on what I am asking